# Removing author and title from footline of beamer slide (madrid theme)

Tags: beamer, header-footer, presentations

[image]

I am writing a beamer presentation using the Madrid theme and I would like to eliminate author and title names from the footnote of the slide. How to do it?

Here is my MWE:

```
           \documentclass{beamer}
           \usetheme{Madrid}
           \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
           \usepackage{appendix}
           \usepackage[numberedbib]{apacite}
           \renewcommand\bibsection{\section[]{\refname}}
           \renewcommand\bibliographytypesize{\tiny}
           \usepackage{textpos}
           \usepackage{eurosym}
           \usepackage{tikz}
           \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
           \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

           \title{Some title}

          \author{guy1  \and guy2  \\
            guy3  \and guy4 }


          \date{Florence, June 13\textsuperscript{th} 2018}

          \begin{document}

         \begin{frame}[plain]
          \titlepage
          \end{frame}

           \begin{frame}{Hallo}
          some nice text
          \end{frame}

          \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick solution: define an empty alternative for the footline by using `\title[]{Some title}`

(I could not compile your MWE and had to remove `\renewcommand\bibsection{\section[]{\refname}}`)

```
           \documentclass{beamer}
           \usetheme{Madrid}
           \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
           \usepackage{appendix}
           \usepackage[numberedbib]{apacite}
%           \renewcommand\bibsection{\section[]{\refname}}
           \renewcommand\bibliographytypesize{\tiny}
           \usepackage{textpos}
           \usepackage{eurosym}
           \usepackage{tikz}
           \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
           \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

           \title[]{Some title}

          \author[]{guy1  \and guy2  \\
            guy3  \and guy4 }


          \date{Florence, June 13\textsuperscript{th} 2018}

          \begin{document}

         \begin{frame}[plain]
          \titlepage
          \end{frame}

           \begin{frame}{Hallo}
          some nice text
          \end{frame}

          \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I needed!  Sorry for the mistake in the MWE  :(